# Jenkins "changes-since-last-success" plugin does not show up in "add post-build action" menu

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed the Jenkins plugin changes-since-last-success.  On the Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage plugins -> installed tab, the plugin shows up as installed and enabled.  Jenkins had been restarted to complete the installation.  The version of the plugin installed is 0.5.  The Jenkins version is 2.7.4.

However, that plugin is not available as a choice on the post-build action menu nor any other action menu in the Jenkins config when I'm trying to use it.

Any suggestions?  Is this plugin compatible with Jenkins 2.7.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin should be compatible with version 2.7.4 and most of the other versions of Jenkins that I am aware of. It should be activated as soon as you install and restart for all the jobs.

In order to access the options provided by the Jenkins plugin [changes-since-last-success](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Changes+Since+Last+Success+Plugin) you should either click the option **Changes since last success** at your build or append the string `/changes-since-last-success/` at the end of your build url.

For example:

```
http://111.11.11.111:8080/job/TEST/26/changes-since-last-success/
```

Then your will get the options as below:

[image: changes since last success]

Comment: afxentios - thanks for your response.  Yes, I do see that option on the build page.  You've answered my question on why it doesn't show up on the build actions.  However, what I am actually looking is a way to capture those changes in a file that can be stored as a build artifact.

Comment: I see. I am not familiar with a way to do that but I see how it could be useful.